# Oracle 11g: How to override default schema tables with test tables for my test user

Tags: database, oracle, testing, schema

I know this can be done, because I've seen it at my last workplace, but I don't know how to replicate!

Basically, there is a MASTER user who has write privileges for all our tables. In our application's DB adapter connection settings, we use `DEFAULT_SCHEMA: MASTER`

I have created a new test user for myself (on the same database as the master user, not using a database link) so that I can freely create test data without messing with real data. Then copied a table for my test user so that I can freely manipulate data: `create table SIMMBOT.real_data_table as select * from MASTER.real_data_table`

The problem is that I don't know how to set up the connection so that Oracle knows to override `MASTER.real_data_table` with my own `SIMMBOT.real_data_table`. I have a hunch that you can't actually do that in the connection settings... so starting from square one, what would I have to do to set up test tables like this? Something like a shared schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code is using fully qualified table names (i.e. `MASTER.real_data_table` or `SIMMBOT.real_data_table`) then there is no way from a configuration standpoint to change what object is being referred to.

Assuming, however, that your code is not using a fully qualified table name-- if it is just selecting from `real_data_table`, then Oracle will first look for an object in the current schema with that name then look for a public synonym with that name.

If you connect as `MASTER`, you can change the current schema

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = SIMMBOT
```

Once you've done that, all unqualified references to a table name will resolve to tables in the `SIMMBOT` schema.  Note that the `MASTER` user would need to be granted appropriate access on the objects in the `SIMMBOT` schema separately-- setting the current schema only affects name resolution, not privileges.  The `SIMMBOT` schema would also need to have every table that the code wants to reference-- there is no way to specify a hierarchy for resolving unqualified names.  You can't tell Oracle to first resolve unqualified names in the `SIMMBOT` schema and then the `MASTER` schema.

An alternative would be to create synonyms for each table and manipulate the synonyms to reference your table for some or all users.  If your application logged in as a third user that did not own any objects-- `APP_USER` for example-- you could create either private synonyms in the `APP_USER` schema that pointed to different objects in different schemas--

```
CREATE SYNONYM app_user.real_data_table FOR simmbot.real_data_table;
CREATE SYNONYM app_user.some_other_table FOR master.some_other_table;
```

or you could create public synonyms that would apply to all users (other than those that owned the objects)

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM real_data_table FOR simmbot.real_data_table;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM some_other_table FOR master.some_other_table;
```